# Search array of objects with a sentence as a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have an array of objects like;

```
{
  id: '121212',
  name: 'request software',
  description: 'Form to request software for your workplace',
  category: 'workplace',
  meta: 'Word Excel Visio'
}
```

Now I want to search these whereby the input for the search is a **sentence** like 'I want to request Microsoft Visio for my workplace today', whereby matches are made on stems (like you'd expect from a search library).

I have tested different node.js modules; **fuzzysort**, **flexsearch**
Both fail to give me back any results when the input is not in a keyword style phrase.

I would imagine that the input sentence needs to be tokenized and stemmed as well, after which matches could be made.

Is there any **library** that would be suited for this or could **Flexsearch** be setup to handle this, since it seems rather capable. However, I cannot find anything in their documentation around this.

I want a simple module that does not require a database.

Comment: try `object.keys()`

Comment: @VirxEC Why would that be helpful?